# How to ping docker container from ansible control node (Mac machine )

Tags: docker, ansible, containers

I have windows docker container in windows 10 host , I am able to ping docker container from docker host ,
but I am unable to ping windows container from mac  machine which is there in the network (all are connected in same router ), I am able to ping windows10 host from mac  machine .

My Main theme in this experiment I need to configure windows container with Ansible , unable to achieve as I am unable to ping windows container from Mac (Ansible installed in it) .

Comment: In general you can't connect directly to containers, especially from other hosts.  "Ping" also isn't really a useful action on its own.  If you're trying to run Ansible, do you need an ssh connection?  How are you starting the containers, and what images are they running?  Can you use Docker's native image system and have containers configure themselves, instead of trying to use Ansible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sad news

> The following networking options are currently NOT supported on
> Windows:
>
> - Windows containers attached to l2bridge, NAT, and overlay networks do    not support communicating over the IPv6 stack.
> - Encrypted container communication via IPsec.
> - HTTP proxy support for containers.
> - Host mode networking
> - Networking on virtualized Azure infrastructure via the transparent network driver.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/architecture#unsupported-features-and-network-options

This translates to: Your windows container, unlike a Linux container can not utilize the Host mode. Therefore your windows container is not available from your physical network that your mac is connected to.

---

You could expose the port of your container on windows just like you would on Linux via

```
docker run -p 80:80 nginx
```

and access the container from your windows host with the exposed port. In the example above `localhost:80`.

However, you are unable to connect to the windows container from the outside as the port mapping only works for `localhost` as stated in the documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

---

Using a bastion host in your ansible inventory is an option, but does not work with winRM. To install an open ssh server on windows is no option either as the blog post by Jordan Borean calls it

> still fairly buggy and not currently

https://www.bloggingforlogging.com/2018/10/14/windows-host-through-ssh-bastion-on-ansible/

---

So, what can you do?

- Run a proxy of your choice on your windows server to forward the traffic to your container

Comment: can you please leborate on this point . "Run a proxy of your choice on your windows server to forward the traffic to your container" how can I do that ?